# How to depth first search through a collection of objects using recursion?

Tags: arrays, object, recursion, depth-first-search, java-5

The depth first search method I'm using to find a particular location by it's ID field, throws a Null pointer exception when looping through a list of location objects.

I debugged the error by setting a breakpoint on the `findLocation()` and `dfs()`, and it only fires the NPE in the `dfs()` for loop. So for example if I specify a location id of '1' the location will be returned correctly, but if I specify a location ID greater than 1 I get an NPE when the code steps into the `dfs()` for loop.

Does anyone know why the `for` loop is giving an NPE on any location ID greater than 1?, although the location ID's range from 1 - 10.

These are the two methods used in conjunction to find a location by ID:

```
public Location findLocation(Integer locationId) {
        Location result = null;
        for (Location l : location) {
            System.out.println("In find method...");
            result = dfs(new HashSet<Location>(), l, locationId); //line 180
            if (result != null)
                System.out.println("You are now in.." + result);
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }


private Location dfs(Set<Location> visitedAlready, Location current,
            Integer id) {
        if (current.id == id)
            return current;
        visitedAlready.add(current); 
        Location result = null;
        for (Location l : current.location) { //line 194
            result = dfs(visitedAlready, l, id);
            if (result != null)
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The exact error that is output is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gmit.Location.dfs(Location.java:194)
    at gmit.Location.findLocation(Location.java:180)
    at gmit.GameParser.parse(GameParser.java:55)
    at gmit.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to know what the exact error message is, and so forth. For that matter, asking each `dfs()` to print current before continuing may be helpful.

There are two potential culprits: first, the passed argument `current` could be null, which will generate errors with `current.id == id` and `current.location` and even possibly `visitedAlready.add(current)` depending on what exactly that method tries to do with the argument. This could happen if the `Location[]` (or whatever the collection is) at `current.location` could have null entries.

The next is that `current.location` itself might be null or something that you can't pull `Locations` out of with a for-loop, so that `Location l : current.location` fails because `current.location` is not right. Indeed it sounds weird for a `Location` object to have a `location` property which contains its child nodes.

In general a recursive depth-first-search looks like this:

```
private Node findById(Set<Node> visited, Node root, Integer id) {
    int i; Node recurse;
    if (root.id == id) {
        return root;
    }
    visited.add(root);
    for (i = 0; i < root.children.length; i += 1) {
        recurse = findById(visited, root.children[i], id)
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If your code is not equivalent to that example you're going to have trouble.

Comment: I'm going to go with what I said in my third paragraph then. Are you sure that `current.location` is not null?

Comment: Okay must check that first, I'll test and report the outcome.